# C# - Outlook VSTO - Exchange - "GetFolderFromID" The message interfaces returned an unknown error

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

I have a problem with my Outlook addin.

First of all, a very very simple overview of the workflow:

- The addin is supposed to get a folder list from the exchange server (public folders).
- The user can select one of this folders.
- The folderid of the selected public folder will be converted from the IdFormat EwsId to HexEntryId to get the mapifolder afterwards.

Then the user can open the folder in Outlook. This is done by setting the `this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder`.

The complete code:

```
// _service is an instance of ExchangeService (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data) 
// The publicFolder is the selected public folder (type of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder)

var objAltPublicFoldId = new AlternatePublicFolderId(IdFormat.EwsId, publicFolder.Id.UniqueId);
var objId = (AlternatePublicFolderId)_service.ConvertId(objAltPublicFoldId, IdFormat.HexEntryId);
var outlookFolder = Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(objId.FolderId);
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = outlookFolder;
```

Most of the time this works good. But some users are getting an error while trying to open the folder.
The exception is always thrown by the method to get the mapifolder object ( `Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(objId.FolderId);`).

The error message is:

> the message interface returned an unknown error if the problem persists restart outlook

But again, this only happens for a few users, but once a user goets this error there is a great chance that this problem will persist until the complete Office installation has been reinstalled. I haven't found any other way to fix this issue so far and the problem seems to come out of nowhere.

All I've found out so far is that the `objId.FolderId` always contains the correct value, and that this affects all folders, not only a specific one. But the user can manually open the folder in Outlook.

- The Outlook versions of the affected people are 2016 and 365.
- The affected assembly is the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.
- The reference to this assembly has following properties:

  - Description: Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library
  - Filetype: ActiveX
  - Identity: {00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\9.6\0\primary
  - Path: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll
  - Version: 9.6.0.0

I really hope that there is someone who's had the same issue and found a solution for that.

Right now, anything could be the source of the error. The Exchange Server, the network, outlook, the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` assembly, the enabled cached mode.

Comment: If you disconnect the pc from the network, do you always and consistently get this error?

Comment: If i disconnect the pc from the network the folder can not be found at the exchange server and therefore the folder can not be opened at outlook. After reconnecting back to the network everything starts working again. For me so far.

Comment: Is the error still raised if the user first expands the PF store in Outlook and navigates to that folder?